# How to remove all the JavaScript from html string on server side in Node Js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to remove all the javascript from an HTML string that will be stored in the database and will be rendered on the client-side later. This HTML comes from the client-side so cannot be trusted. I don't want to use any iframe. If the answer will be an algorithm or a library suggestion it will be accepted.

Comment: This is a complex question, I suggest you look for an existing library that filters out javascript strings rather than trying to write something yourself;  if you try and write your own filter there is a risk someone will find a way to bypass it.

Comment: Exactly that's why I don't want to do that... What do you think about xssfilter from npmjs? I found it just now...